# How to make a vim map that will make a command using the current selected file on NerdTREE?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, nerdtree

Take the example below:

[img http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/j6.png](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/j6.png)

How to create a mapping that will perform `rm contas.ls`?

Comment: The image link above is dead

Answer (score 2):

NERDTree has a menu system. In Nerdtree buffer press `m` you will see the menu.

So you could create a mapping like:

```
map <buffer> ,d mdy
```

to delete selected file. This will actually trigger the menu.

if you want to remove file silently without triggering menu, you could:

```
map <buffer> ,d :call g:NERDTreeFileNode.GetSelected().delete()|call NERDTreeRender()<cr>
```

you may want to put the mapping in autocmd, so that it only effects nerdtree buffer.

Comment: I'm having a problem, my default mappings are overwriting NERDTree's mappings. I mapped "m" to something, so I can't see that menu you're talking about...

Comment: in nerdtree buffer, press `?` see which key is the menu. also the 2nd option should work anyway.

Comment: I'm trying to get what you've done, the problem is, what if I want to call commands other than rm?

Comment: I don't have rm call in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
:h NERDTreeKeymapAPI

4.1. Key map API                                           *NERDTreeKeymapAPI*

NERDTreeAddKeyMap({options})                             *NERDTreeAddKeyMap()*
    Adds a new keymapping for all NERD tree buffers.
    {options} must be a dictionary, and must contain the following keys:
    "key" - the trigger key for the new mapping
    "callback" - the function the new mapping will be bound to
    "quickhelpText" - the text that will appear in the quickhelp (see
    |NERDTree-?|)

    Additionally, a "scope" argument may be supplied. This constrains the
    mapping so that it is only activated if the cursor is on a certain object.
    That object is then passed into the handling method. Possible values are:
        "FileNode" - a file node
        "DirNode" - a directory node
        "Node" - a file or directory node
        "Bookmark" - A bookmark
        "all" - the keymap is not constrained to any scope (default). When
        thei is used, the handling function is not passed any arguments.


    Example: >
        call NERDTreeAddKeyMap({
            \ 'key': 'foo',
            \ 'callback': 'NERDTreeCDHandler',
            \ 'quickhelpText': 'echo full path of current node' })
            \ 'scope': 'DirNode'

        function! NERDTreeCDHandler(dirnode)
            call a:dirnode.changeToDir()
        endfunction
<
    This code should sit in a file like ~/.vim/nerdtree_plugin/mymapping.vim.
    It adds a (redundant) mapping on 'foo' which changes vim's CWD to that of
    the current dir node. Note this mapping will only fire when the cursor is
    on a directory node.
```

There are some typos in the help doc example code ('echo full path...' when it doesn't, closing of call a line early), but here's a working example:

```
call NERDTreeAddKeyMap({
    \ 'key': '<F3>',
    \ 'callback': 'NERDTreeExample',
    \ 'quickhelpText': 'echo full path of current node',
    \ 'scope': 'FileNode' })

function! NERDTreeExample(filenode)
    echo a:filenode.path._strForGlob()
endfunction
```

There are *a lot* of functions in NERDTree. You can change the function above to this to explore a bit:

```
function! NERDTreeExample(filenode)
    echo keys(a:filenode)
endfunction
```

The previous example used `path._strForGlob`, which I found using this, once I decided "path" was a likely candidate (there is much else in there):

```
function! NERDTreeExample(filenode)
    echo keys(a:filenode.path)
endfunction
```

Read the docs, though. They tell you where to save things, etc. You can also poke through the script files that come with it. It's all set up in folds that are pretty easily scannable when collapsed.

Answer (score 1):

For the simplest cases, like the one in your question, you can do:

```
:!rm filename       " works with tab completion
```

or

```
:!rm <C-r><C-f>     " inserts the filename under the cursor
```

NERDTree provides a small subset of the built-in Netrw's features, one thing that isn't in that subset is the `D` mapping for deleting a file or directory. Did you try netrw (`:EX`, `:Vex`, `:Sex`, `:h netrw`) before installing NERDTree?